# Python socket not returning data to ios NSURLConnection

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, sockets, nsurlconnection

I am trying to make a simple python server that when conected returns a string:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 
PORT = 8080
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

And I am trying to connect to this with a simple NSURLConnection

```
    NSString *post = @"test";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //NSURLResponse *response;
    //NSError *err;
    NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [conn start];

    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

}
```

In the python app I am getting the print out of connected by however my delegate methods in objective c are not being called. Any pointers would be great, thank you!